# Align image both horizontally and vertically

Tags: restructuredtext, docutils

Using `docutils`, it doesn't seem possible to align an image both horizontally and vertically in reStructuredText. Vertical alignment is only accepted for substitutions, while horizontal alignment only works for inline images, thus:

```
.. image:: some/image.png
   :align: middle
```

and

```
.. |name| image:: some/image.png
   :align: center
```

crash.

Is there a way to control both the vertical and horizontal alignments?

Comment: According to the docutils [image directive specification](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image) `align` can take the values "top", "middle" or "bottom" for vertical alignment and "left", "center", or "right" for horizontal alignment. What do you mean your code examples crash? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: It’s a bit saddening that they dump a class into the html instead of actually using the align html attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer:

Since `:align` is based on the HTML definition of alignment, it doesn't make sense (in general) to align images vertically in the page (in my case, I'm doing a presentation, so vertically aligning in slides makes sense).

For that reason, standalone images can only be horizontally aligned, while inline images can only be vertically aligned (on the base line).